# Problema con estilos asignados con JS

Tags: javascript, css, html5, animación

Es la primera vez que solicito ayuda a través de este medio y agradezco a todos de antemano la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Estoy desarrollando un sitio web con unas animaciones html5, y las posiciones de algunos elementos se basan la posición de otro, la cosa es que cuando cargas la página por primera vez, las imaganes no se ubican bien, pero si recargas (asumo que ya está en cache la posicón del objeto de "referencia") si se ubican bien las otras imagenes, pero si vuelves a recargar limpiando cache (ctrl + F5) todo vuelve a estar mal, en el siguiente vínculo se puede ver el problema, aun el sitio está en desarrollo así que tiene algunas cosas por corregir, pero lo que viene al caso es en la "sección 2" (imagen de una casa con otros elementos):

http://visualstudio66.com/aislante/

El código que estoy usando es:

**estilos.js**

```js
$('.nube').css('left', $('.house').offset().left - ($('.nube').width() * 1.6));
$('.sun').css('left', $('.house').offset().left + $('.house').outerWidth() - ($('.sun').width() * 1));
$('.fire').css('left', $('.house').offset().left - ($('.fire').width() * 1.3));
$('.logohouse').css('left', $('.sun').offset().left + $('.sun').outerWidth() - ($('.logohouse').width() * 1.2));
$('.stop1').css('left', $('.nube').offset().left + ($('.stop1').width() * 0.8));
$('.stop2').css('left', $('.sun').offset().left + ($('.stop2').width() * 0.1));
$('.stop3').css('left', $('.fire').offset().left + ($('.stop3').width() * 0.8));
$('.temp').css('left', $('.house').offset().left + ($('.temp').width() * 0.3));
$('.plus1').css('left', $('.house').offset().left - ($('.plus1').width() * 2.6));
$('.plus2').css('left', $('.house').offset().left + $('.house').outerWidth() - ($('.plus2').width() * 7));
$('.plus3').css('left', $('.house').offset().left - ($('.plus3').width() * 2.5));
$('.plus4').css('left', $('.house').offset().left + ($('.plus4').width() * 1.8));
$('.plus5').css('left', $('.house').offset().left + ($('.plus5').width() * 4.2));
$('.tooltip1').css('left', $('.plus1').offset().left + $('.plus1').width());
$('.tooltip2').css('left', $('.plus2').offset().left + $('.plus2').width());
$('.tooltip3').css('left', $('.plus3').offset().left + $('.plus3').width());
$('.tooltip4').css('left', $('.plus4').offset().left + $('.plus4').width());
$('.tooltip5').css('left', $('.plus5').offset().left + $('.plus5').width());
```

```html
**Código fuente html**
<div class="section" id="section1">
      <div class="contenido1">
                <img alt="Nube" data-wow-delay="1.5s" data-wow-duration="1.5s" class="nube wow bounceInLeft1" src="imgs/house/nube.png">
                <img alt="Casa" data-wow-delay=".5s" class="house wow bounceIn" src="imgs/house/house.png">
                <img alt="Sol" data-wow-delay="1s" data-wow-duration="1.5s" class="sun wow bounceInRight1" src="imgs/house/sol.png">
                <img alt="Fuego" data-wow-delay="2s" data-wow-duration="1.5s" class="fire wow bounceInLeft2" src="imgs/house/fire.png">
                <img alt="Aislante Panamá" data-wow-delay="2.5s" class="logohouse wow bounceIn" src="imgs/house/logo.png">
                <img alt="Stop" data-wow-delay="4s" class="stop1 wow bounceIn" src="imgs/house/stop.png">
                <img alt="Stop" data-wow-delay="4s" class="stop2 wow bounceIn" src="imgs/house/stop.png">
                <img alt="Stop" data-wow-delay="4s" class="stop3 wow bounceIn" src="imgs/house/stop.png">
                <img alt="Temperatura" data-wow-delay="5s" class="temp wow bounceIn" src="imgs/house/temp.png">
            </div>
   <div data-wow-delay="6s" class="pluses wow fadeIn">
    <div class="tooltip">
                 <a href="#openModal1">
                     <span class="tooltiptext tooltip1"><p><strong>Aislante Acústico</strong><br>Click para ver más...</p></span>
                        <img alt="Plus" data-wow-delay="0s" class="plus1 wow pulse" src="imgs/house/plus.png">
     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="tooltip">
                 <a href="#openModal2">
                     <span class="tooltiptext tooltip2"><p><strong>Optimización Térmica</strong><br>Click para ver más...</p></span>
                        <img alt="Plus" data-wow-delay="0s" class="plus2 wow pulse" src="imgs/house/plus.png">
     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="tooltip">
                 <a href="#openModal3">
                     <span class="tooltiptext tooltip3"><p><strong>Resistencia al  Fuego</strong><br>Click para ver más...</p></span>
                        <img alt="Plus" data-wow-delay="0s" class="plus3 wow pulse" src="imgs/house/plus.png">
     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="tooltip">
                 <a href="#openModal4">
                     <span class="tooltiptext tooltip4"><p><strong>Ahorro de Energía</strong><br>Click para ver más...</p></span>
                        <img alt="Plus" data-wow-delay="0s" class="plus4 wow pulse" src="imgs/house/plus.png">
     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="tooltip">
                 <a href="#openModal5">
                     <span class="tooltiptext tooltip5"><p><strong>Calidad y Confort</strong><br>Click para ver más...</p></span>
                        <img alt="Plus" data-wow-delay="0s" class="plus5 wow pulse" src="imgs/house/plus.png">
     </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="openModal1" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
     <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
     <h2>Aislante Acústico</h2>
                    <img alt="Fuego" src="imgs/house/sound.jpg">
     <p>Nuestro producto de celulosa tiene una clasificación de transmisión de sonido hasta STC 80 y tiene un coeficiente de reducción de ruido de NRC 80 o más</p>
    </div>
   </div>
            <div id="openModal2" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
     <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
     <h2>Optimización Térmica</h2>
                    <img alt="Térmico" src="imgs/house/optimiza.jpg">
     <p>Comprobado con cámaras térmicas, el aislante de celulosa reduce la temperatura interior hasta 10º grados, con una clasificación de resistencia R-19</p>
    </div>
   </div>
            <div id="openModal3" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
     <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
     <h2>Resistencia al  Fuego</h2>
                    <img alt="Fuego" src="imgs/house/fire.jpg">
     <p>Las fibras de celulosa son tratadas químicamente para agregar resistencia al fuego, lo que lo hace un producto Clase A (ASTM E84)</p>
    </div>
   </div>
            <div id="openModal4" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
     <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
     <h2>Ahorro de Energía</h2>
                    <img alt="Térmico" src="imgs/house/economia.jpg">
     <p>Mejora la eficiencia energética entre un 30% y un 60%, lo cual representa una reducción en su factura</p>
    </div>
   </div>
            <div id="openModal5" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
     <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
     <h2>Calidad y Confort</h2>
                    <img alt="Fuego" src="imgs/house/confort.jpg">
     <p>Previene la presencia de insectos, además evita la oxidación, acumulación de humedad, moho y hongos, lo que extiende la vida útil de todas las estructuras</p>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

No soy experto en javascript, así que me estoy volviendo loco tratando de encontrar la solución, cualquier cosa que sea necesaria para verificar me avisan.

Saludos,
Andrés

Comment: En que parte del documento pusiste la referencia hacia el script?

Comment: Al final del documento, de hecho si lo pongo al principio no funciona

Comment: Probé poniendo la referencia al script en el head o al final del documento y el problema persiste

Answer (score 0):

Si el problema es que se aplican a veces los estilos y a veces no, podrías probar de escribir todos el código jQuery dentro del evento 
**'ready'**. El evento ready se dispara cuando el documento html ha sido cargado.

// el evento ready sobre documento

$(document).ready(function(){

// aquí irían todos tus estilos

});

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, voy a probar y les cuento

Comment: Ya probé con el evento **"ready"**, como me indicaste, pero el problema persiste, la referencia al script la probe en el **"head"** y al final de documento y sigue igual.

Lo curioso es que solo sale mal la primera vez que se accede al sitio o cuando borras cache, luego siempre sale bien.

Answer (score 0):

Te dire algo, eso es porque cada vez que usa $(),.css(),.offset() estas llamando a una funcion de jquery y que a su vez llama a una funcion de javascript , y esto hace que javascript tenga unos problemas graves de optimizacion. Cada vez que usas esas funcioned javascript tiene que buscar el elemento, tomar estilos, hacer calculos y definir estilos,  y esto lo hace en cada linea de tu codigo y cada vez que llama a una funcion ,te recomiendo que uses variables en javascript para elementos que se repitan, asi javascript no tiene que buscar y buscar el elemento y sus estilos en cada linea de tu codigo, por ejemplo:

```
//veo que en tu codigo se repite mucho la siguiente linea:

  $('.house').offset().left

//En vez de repetirlo unas 4 o 5 veces declaras una variable para que no llame a funciones y tome estilos las veces que lo repites

    var house = $('.house').offset().left;

// y pones esa variable en lugar de lo primero
```

Y porque la primera ves no funciona bien? Desde mi humilde punto de vista, creo que es porque al tu entrar por primera vez en una pagina, no tienes nada en cache, pero despues el navegador guarda en cache casi toda la pagina, lo que hace que la pagina cargue mas rapido y a su vez el javascript y por ende el codigo se ejecute con menos errores de optimacion

Comment: Probé hacendo lo que dices, cambiando los elementos que se repiten por variables y sigue igual, te agradezco mucho la explicación de como optimizarlo con variables.

Definitivamente el tema es que no tiene de donde tomar "left" de house" hasta que se cargó por completo la página, por eso al recargar si funciona bien, el asunto es que ya probé con "$(document).ready(function()" y ni así funciona

Comment: Osea, no entiendo, dices que no tienes de donde tomar left de house? Explicame eso

Comment: La cosa es que yo defino el "height" de house (pues me importa más el alto que el ancho en la página) y el "width" se dá automáticamente por proporción, así que el "left" no está predefinido, se define al posicionar house en el navegador

Comment: Parece que encontré la solución, cambiando la propiedad de cada imagen "left" por "margin-right", lo sé es raro, pero parece que vá a funcionar así,
voy a términar de cambiar todo y les cuento

Comment: Y te funciona??

Comment: Si, funciona! jejeje es muy raro, quedaría así:

Comment: `var house = $('.house').height();

 $('.nube').css('margin-right', house * 1.4);
 $('.sun').css('margin-left', house * 1.52);`

Comment: De hecho no es raro, left por defecto es 0, y creo que esos elementos lo que tienen es margin-left y right, tal como pusiste, te sugiero que analizes un poco tu codigo css y javascript e intentes descubrir porque te funciona con margin-right y margin-left, eso te dara mas experiencia y te ayudara professionalmente

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda y consejos, créeme que son muy valiosos para mi, saludos